# Issues with MYSQLi INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason, I am unable to store to insert data in the following database table. I am certain the connection is fine since I am successfully retrieving data from this database using `select` but I seem to have a problem with `insert`

```
// Track user data in database
// Array must be converted to strings
$track = "INSERT INTO resources_record (name,email,stage,format,topic,cost,mentor)
          VALUES ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 5, '6')";

// Execute track query
 mysqli_query($con, $track);
```

It just doesn't insert anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the structure of the table `resources_record`. Also, for funsies, try:     `INSERT INTO \`resources_record\` (\`name\`,\`email\`,\`stage\`,\`format\`,\`topic\`,\`cost\`,\`mentor\`) VALUES ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 5, '6')`

Comment: @Your Common Sense what duplicate u found on two different topics? "mysql reserved words vs backticks" and "dev env"

Comment: @user3907211, as @ScottMcGready said u should have backticks around coulumn names. also you should understand why. to "escape" reserved words. actually you need them only with `format`. read more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Comment: If in doubt, bacticks